# Positioning Text to appear Identically on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, positioning

I have a site that has a box with some text in it. When I view it in Chrome, its right at the top, so I have put a `padding-top` css rule in to element which lines it up correctly on Chrome, but on Firefox, the text is initially centred correctly, and the css rule ruins that. How can I code it (preferably without a browser detector on the server) so that it pads down the text in chrome, but not in firefox?

EDIT:

```
.footer input[type="submit"]
{
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: The best solution is making a solid layout, this would give you the same results in chrome and firefox. If you could show us a CSS and HTML example it would be helpful too :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it (at least for the moment) with this code

```
padding: 8px 10px 6px;
-webkit-padding-after: 8px;
```

Thank you `Roddy of the Frozen Pea` for the `webkit` reference

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is that you utilize a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to remove the differences between the browsers. Without seeing the specific code, it's hard to say if this will 100% fix your issue.

Comment: definitely gonna use that code in future, but sadly in this case, it didn't work

Comment: Use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to recreate the scenario for us to see and play with.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only those two browsers you care about, you can add webkit-specific CSS just for Chrome. So, in your example, you need an extra `padding-top` for Chrome: `-webkit-padding-before`. This will apply the padding only to webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.) but not to Firefox or IE or Opera.

Your best bet, however, would be to apply a CSS reset and then style identically for all browsers. If that's not an option, then you can target specific engines (webkit, etc) like I mentioned above. This is not, however, recommended or considered "best practice."